# Applications of logic

Tags: logic, soft-question

What are some applications of symbolic logic? I tried using Google and Bing but just got a bunch of book recommendations, and links to articles I did not understand.

Comment: Very basic symbolic logic is connected with circuit design.

Comment: Symbolic logic lies at the heart of much mathematics. Its "application" is to provide a logical foundation for other parts of mathematics, such as set theory and computation theory. It has little direct applicability outside of mathematics itself, though parts of it (eg deductive logic) are used extensively in computer hardware and software design. Many parts of mathematics have no "application" as such; mathematicians have been studying prime numbers for almost 3,000 years and nobody found an application for the theory of primes until internet commerce came along.

Comment: Godel's Incompleteness Theorem is used all the time by people who think it proves God exists, or proves God doesn't exist, or has some other major philosophical implication. See Torkel Franzen's book for lots of discussion of (faulty) applications of Godel.

Answer (score 5):

Among others, logic has application in

- [natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), for example in formalisms like [HPSG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-driven_phrase_structure_grammar) or [CCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_categorial_grammar);
- programming languages, where [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) plays a major role;
- correctness, verification and concurrency in computer science, for example [Hoare logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic), but also things like [CTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic).
- various semantic-related data models like [ontologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29) or the [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) or [OWL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language) file formats, even some databases could fit in here;
- tree processing (like [tree automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_automaton)), for example things like [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) rely on logic very much.

Of course, it's not only *symbolic* logic (other techniques are sure to be there), but symbolic logic *does* have a say in all of the above points (even if it is far from the most important aspect).

I hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Some would say that symbolic logic, of its nature, just *is* a branch of applicable mathematics already, from the very outset.

Compare: classical mechanics, say, is that branch of applied (and so applicable!) mathematics which constructs models (heavily idealised but useful models) of various classes of physical phenomena. Symbolic logic is that branch of applicable mathematics whose business is to construct models (heavily idealised but useful models) of mathematical reasoning.

We can then, as @dtlarek notes, unsurprisingly use these formal models of mathematical reasoning in various formal computer-science applications. But arguably these are, in a good sense, secondary applications.

Comment: I would say classical mechanics is a branch of physics. One that of course makes heavy use of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the direct uses that everyone else is mentioning, learning symbolic logic has indirect benefits. Indirectly, understanding symbolic logic helps to understand where people go wrong in their everyday conversations. For instance, politicians will often use tricks to convince people that their viewpoint is right. Understanding logic helps you quickly pull apart bad arguments.

Comment: Oh I wish this was true (having taught logic for decades!). But I doubt it. "Critical thinking" or "Informal Logic" courses might do the trick, but not formal logic. A friend once gave students the same quiz twice, getting them to evaluate informal arguments, once before and once after his formal logic course. The students did worse *after* the course ...

Comment: ... You can understand why: after the course, the students had *two* things to think about, the informal arguments and their not always well-understood shiny new formal tools, so the chances of muddle increased!

Comment: For an interesting example of a first-rate logician who seemed to have trouble with "pulling apart bad arguments", see [Gottlob Frege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottlob_Frege).

Comment: That make sense. I have found the reverse to be true. The formality behind logic and math helped me understand softer topics better... or at least they gave me the perception of understanding them better. I guess you never know with these things.

Answer (score 0):

It aids mathematicians to explain or describe something i.e. a specific statement in such a way that other mathematicians will understand, also it makes the statement open to manipulation, furthermore it is less time consuming to write an equation than the whole statement. Also it is a universal language which is understood by all and there is no error when translating text, and finally you can focus on the important part of the statement.